# Configure meteor accounts to register & sign in with phone number

Tags: meteor, accounts

I would like to make some modifications to the meteor accounts system (*remove email address, put phone no. in its place*). My question would be how to do that (i thought of modifying accounts-password), and how to do that (e.g. creating a new package, or simply rewrite the git cloned accounts base)?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The meteor accounts package does not **require** an email, users need either an email or a username. So you could use their phone number as a username and stick with the default package.

See: http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_createuser

> On the client, you must pass password and at least one of username or
>   email — enough information for the user to be able to log in again
>   later. On the server, you do not need to specify password, but the
>   user will not be able to log in until it has a password (eg, set with
>   Accounts.setPassword).

Comment: accounts-base, accounts-password or both?

Comment: How can this be used so that the user doesn't have to enter their password every time the launch the app on their phone?